# Spring Boot JPA repository error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, repository

i am try using spring boot with hibernate-mysql for learning
i follow the spring boot youtube tutorial and make some change for jpa hibernate-mysql

When run as "spring boot app", it was working fine.
When run as "maven package" on pom.xml, it was failed on "TESTS"

error:

```
2015-09-18 10:26:19.599  INFO 8328 --- [           main] demo.DemoApplicationTests                : Starting DemoApplicationTests on Noir with PID 8328 (D:\eclipse\project\demo\target\test-classes started by Phane in D:\eclipse\project\demo)
2015-09-18 10:26:19.667  INFO 8328 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@1d0737c8: startup date [Fri Sep 18 10:26:19 SGT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-09-18 10:26:19.768  WARN 8328 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\eclipse\project\demo\target\classes\filmRental\JpaConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:266)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:270)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
```

this is the java classes:
**DemoApplication.java**

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import filmRental.Staff;
import filmRental.StaffRepository;
import filmRental.StaffServiceImpl;

@SpringBootApplication

    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }
    }

    @ComponentScan ("filmRental")
    @Component
    class StaffCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner
    {

        @Override
        public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception 
        {
            for(Staff staff : this.sf.findAll())
            {
                System.out.println(staff.getStaffID() + " > " + staff.getFirstName());
            }

        }

        @Autowired StaffServiceImpl sf;

    }
```

**StaffRestController**

```
package demo;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import filmRental.Staff;
import filmRental.StaffServiceImpl;

@RestController
@ComponentScan ("filmRental")
public class StaffRestController 
{
    @RequestMapping ("/staff")
    public Collection<Staff> listStaff()
    {
        return sf.findAll();
    }

    @Autowired StaffServiceImpl sf;
}
```

**StaffServiceImpl.java**

```
package filmRental;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class StaffServiceImpl 
{
//  @PersistenceContext
//  private EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    private StaffRepository sf;

    public List<Staff> findAll()
    {
        return sf.findAll();
    }
}
```

**StaffRepository.java**

```
package filmRental;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
public interface StaffRepository extends JpaRepository<Staff, Byte>{}
```

**Staff.java**

```
package filmRental;

import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table (name ="Staff")
public class Staff 
{
    private byte staffID;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private byte[] picture;
    private String email;
    private byte storeID;
    private boolean active;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;
    private Address address;

    @Id
    @Column (name="staff_id")
    public byte getStaffID()
    {
        return staffID;
    }

    public void setStaffID(byte staffID) 
    {
        this.staffID = staffID;
    }

    @Column (name = "first_name")
    public String getFirstName() 
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) 
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column (name = "last_name")
    public String getLastName() 
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column (name = "picture", columnDefinition="BLOB")
    public byte[] getPicture() 
    {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(byte[] picture) 
    {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    @Column (name = "email")
    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) 
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column (name = "store_id")
    public byte getStoreID()
    {
        return storeID;
    }

    public void setStoreID(byte storeID) 
    {
        this.storeID = storeID;
    }

    @Column (name = "active")
    public boolean getActive() 
    {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) 
    {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Column (name = "username")
    public String getUserName() 
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Column (name = "password")
    public String getPassword() 
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column (name = "last_update")
    public Timestamp getLastUpdate() 
    {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Timestamp lastUpdate) 
    {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

**JpaConfig.java**

```
package filmRental;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class JpaConfig 
{

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() 
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() 
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() 
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() 
    {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>`enter code here`

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: First of all the `@ComponentScan` should not be on your `@Component` but your application class. Second you are using Spring Boot and are very hard trying not to use Spring Boot. You can remove your `JpaConfig` and simply put a couple of properties in `application.properties` and have all that auto configured for you. Finally you are using Hibernate5 for which Spring Boot 1.2 doesn't have support (as that depends on Spring 4.1 which doesn't have hibernate support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot then use Spring Boot also the `@ComponentScan` should go on your application class. (remove it from your command line runner and controller).

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan ({"demo","filmRental"})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
class StaffCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired StaffServiceImpl sf;

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        for(Staff staff : this.sf.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(staff.getStaffID() + " > " + staff.getFirstName());
        }
    }
}
```

Next in your pom remove the `spring-data-jpa`, `hibernate` and `persistence-api` dependencies and replace with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now you have dependencies that work together instead of trying to figure out a working combination.

Spring Boot already does auto configuration for you remove your `JpaConfig` and put the following properties in your `application.properties` (automatically loaded by Spring Boot!).

```
spring.datasource.url=<datasource-url>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=<driver-class-name>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>

spring.jpa.database-platform=<hibernate-dialect>
spring.jpa.show-sql=<show-sql>
```

For the entity scan use `@EntityScan` on the application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan ({"demo","filmRental"})
@EntityScan("filmRental")
public class DemoApplication { ... }
```

Spring Boot now auto configures the `DataSource`, `EntityManagerFactory`, transactions, detects Spring Data JPA and enables repositories. I would suggest moving the `DemoApplication` and everything else in the `filmRental` package that way you can remove the `@ComponentScan` and `@EntityScan` from the `DemoApplication`.

Comment: Great!
Thanks! It is working!

step 1: delete JpaConfig
step 2: moving to same package
step 3: update applpication.properties
step 4: remove dependency
step 5: remove unnecessary annotation
step 6: add jdbc driver dependency to pom.xml